# How to make spacing between wijmo grid rows

Tags: html, css, angular

I use this code for display grid.How do I change style of wijmo grid and make spacing between rows ? 
    How can I change it?
I want to change grid to this picture and when hover rows set bax-shadow
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg1mx.png

```
    <div class="col-12 mygrid">
                               <wj-flex-grid #flex [itemsSource]="view" [autoGenerateColumns]="false"
                                   [autoSearch]="true" [quickAutoSize]="false" [selectionMode]="'CellRange'"
                                   [showSelectedHeaders]="'Column'" [stickyHeaders]="false" [isReadOnly]="true"
                                   [headersVisibility]="1" class="scroller saipa-h-20 overflow-auto"
                                   (initialized)="initializeGrid(flex)" (selectionChanged)="selectionChange(flex)">
                                   <wj-flex-grid-column [width]="'*'" [header]="'شماره قرارداد'"
                                       [binding]="'AgreementNo'" [dataType]="'String'">
                                   </wj-flex-grid-column>

                                   <wj-flex-grid-column [width]="'*'" [header]="'نام'" [binding]="'Name'"
                                       [dataType]="'String'">

                                   </wj-flex-grid-column>
                                   <wj-flex-grid-column [width]="'*'" [header]="'کد'" [binding]="'Code'"
                                       [dataType]="'String'">
                                   </wj-flex-grid-column>
                                   <wj-flex-grid-column [binding]="'crudButtons'" [header]="'انتخاب'" [width]="80">
                                   </wj-flex-grid-column>
                                   <div id="tplBtnChoose" style="display:none">
                                       <button type="button" id="btnPersonSelect"
                                           class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o saipa-red-hover saipa-red-click saipa-grid-fontsize saipa-no-border bg-transparent">
                                       </button>
                                   </div>
                               </wj-flex-grid>
                           </div>
```

Comment: Could add online example please?

Comment: No ,I can't add online example because wijmo grid is not free @simpleDmitry